# how can I add checkbox in menu items,while my menuitems are dynamically loaded

Tags: extjs

I did smthing like this..

```
    var mymenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu');
    for (var i = 0; i < store.getCount(); ++i){
    var record = store.getAt(i);

    var menuItem =  Ext.create('Ext.menu.Item' ,{
        xtype: 'menucheckitem',               
        checked : false,
        text : record.data.rollName,
        value : record.data.rollId          

    });       

    mymenu.add(menuItem);
}
```

but i am not getting checkbox in my menu.only Display field is visible.

Comment: You're not creating the right class type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two types of `xtype` property that Ext understands, which are closely connected to each other.

```
items:[{
    xtype:'menucheckitem',
}]
```

will create you an item of xtype `menucheckitem`. This only works if there is a type which has xtype `menucheckitem` assigned.

```
Ext.define('Ext.menu.Item',{
    xtype:'menucheckitem'
```

will define the type `Ext.menu.Item` and *assign* to that type the xtype `menucheckitem`, such that the first example works.

What are you doing? Mixing both together to some soup:

```
var menuItem =  Ext.create('Ext.menu.Item' ,{
    xtype: 'menucheckitem',
```

This will create an item of type `Ext.menu.Item`, and set the object's xtype property to `menucheckitem` (this won't have any effect, because you are not defining a type, but creating a single instance)

What you want is the following:

```
var menuItem =  Ext.create('Ext.menu.CheckItem' ,{
```

without the xtype line!